# A scanner driver that attach files from computer

Tags: drivers, scanner, attachments

**Edited for better description**

I have a rather specific problem while using an old internally developed application at my work.

I need to attach a file, but the application only has a scan functionality, not file attach. Changes to the application is unfortunately not possible.

So the only way to "attach" files now, is by printing the file and then scan it - in the long run this isn't all that smart.

So my question is - are there any program/driver, that adds a "fictive" printing driver that doesn't actualy scan but instead prompts for a file? (somewhat like PDFCreator adds a fictive printing driver that doesn't actually print)

Or do you think it's so specific that no one has bothered to make such a driver/program?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. In it's current form, it might end up being closed. Can you [edit] this question with some detail about the program you are working with and what you've already tried?

Comment: @CharlieRB , thanks for your comments. I've attempted to adjust the description, hopefully the problem is clearer now?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've tried to change the description to better explain the problem, I hope it is clearer now thanks.

Comment: Much clearer. However, now that I understand the problem, I don't have a solution for you.

Comment: Twain Importer is a "virtual Twain driver that imports images into any Twain-compatible scan application" (http://www.scanworkssoftware.com/twainimporter.aspx). You can download a trial version from http://www.scanworkssoftware.com/products/twnimporter/4.0/twainimporterpro.zip.

Comment: @jaume thanks! That's just precisely what I was looking for! You can just add it as answer to this question, then it can be closed :)

Comment: Great it worked for you, I'm glad I could help. I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twain Importer is a "virtual Twain driver that imports images into any Twain-compatible scan application".

It runs on Windows XP/7/2008 Server/2008 Server R2 (both 32-bit and 64-bit versions) (see http://www.scanworkssoftware.com/twainimporter.aspx for more information).

You can download a **trial version** from http://www.scanworkssoftware.com/products/twnimporter/4.0/twainimporterpro.zip.